# cannot pass Array inside UseState()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

//error i get inside Console (cannot get Value of event_id)

```
 useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(function() {


  if (post.details) {
    console.log(post.details[0].event_id,'EventId') // consoleLog => 38 ||perfectly Working
    const newArr2 = []
    for (var i = 0 ; i <= post.details.length; i++){
      newArr2.push(post.details[i].event_id) //cannot get Value of event_id
    }
    setArray(array.concat(newArr2))
  } }, 1000);
  },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

With the details that you have shared try changing to this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (post.details) {
            const newArr2 = post.details.map(detail => {
                console.log(detail.event_id);
                return detail.event_id;
            });
            setArray(array.concat(newArr2));
        }
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: it is working but i just have 10 values & it is storing 79 values inside SetArray and running infinite times y, how to add loop ( i ) condition inside mapping

Comment: I'm not sure what is calling this `useEffect` function, need more details to help you out.

Comment: useEffect(() => { .then((data) => setPost(data));  }, []); end here-----------------------
  (//2nd useEffect) useEffect(() => {     
    setTimeout(function () { const newArr2 = post.details.map(detail => {
                console.log(detail.event_id);
                return detail.event_id;
            });
            setArray(array.concat(newArr2)); }, 1000);
  }, []);

Comment: Thank you it is Finally working @Bharat sir

Comment: Nice :)  edit the changes let me see what changed

Comment: useEffect(() => { , [post]); just Added post api response condition in useEffect || it is rendering 3-4 times but got the ids inside State ... thanks again sir